# Shut down Cortana for good

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Can anyone help me out? I've searched here on Superuser, I've searched Google, I've searched everywhere, and I cannot for the life of me find out how to shut down Cortana. Mind you, I have a new laptop, so maybe information hasn't caught up yet.

She's everywhere. She's there when I Alt+Tab. She's there in the corner. I've shut down permissions everywhere I can find. But she's still there. Can anyone tell me once and for all how to shut down Cortana? I shouldn't have to fight with Microsoft just to get Cortana to leave me alone.

In case it matters, I have Windows 10 build 19041.630.